# External hard drive is unusable after using it as a Time Machine backup for a new Mac. How do I reformat an external hard drive?

Tags: external-hard-drive, time-machine

I recently got a new mac and used my external 1TB hard drive as a Time Machine backup. It had me erase everything on the hard drive, and when it was complete I was able to restore my new mac using the external hard drive.

I have now connected the external hard drive to my Windows PC, and it is not accessible through File Explorer/Other means to copy my files back over, since it only used around 300gb.

I think the entire drive has been formatted for the time machine, and I have tried to reformat but I have been unsuccessful with doing so.

I can see the External under `Devices and Printers` and have tried updating the drivers, etc. But I cannot use it to transfer files anymore.

Comment: The format used for Mac isn't natively supported in Windows but you should be able to format it again at Disk Management.

Comment: Or remove all partitions and then format NTFS with a third-party tool such as free DiskGenius, https://www.diskgenius.com/

Answer (score 0):

The issue was due to me using the whole hard drive as a Mac Time Machine.

After getting access to my mac, I was able to plug it in and erase it/format it for Mac and Windows use.